# Allow blank spaces in ag-grid filter

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, visual-studio-code, ag-grid-angular

I'm facing a problem with ag grid filter. I'm seeing that is ignoring the white spaces.

Where can i set to the grid to allow blank spaces in the filter?
Do you know any trick?
Which part of the grid i can set acceptEmptyValuesFilter or something like that??

```
onTextChange() {
    this.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(mySearchTextBox);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set empty value.

```
  onTextChange() {
        this.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(' ');
      }
```